# Application contexts provide a means for resolving text messages?

Tags: spring

One of the main advatage stated for Application Context is below :-

> Application contexts provide a means
>   for resolving text messages

Could somebody explain with brief example what does that mean?

Second is there any overhead of using Application contexts  over BeanFactory as i have seen most of the application using BeanFactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the declaration of `ApplicationContext`:

```
public interface ApplicationContext extends
    ListableBeanFactory,
    HierarchicalBeanFactory,
    MessageSource,
    ApplicationEventPublisher,
    ResourcePatternResolver {
```

One of the interfaces it extends is `MessageSource`:

> Strategy interface for resolving messages, with support for the parameterization and internationalization of such messages.

From [MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) Javadoc. This means you can use application context as a message source for your application with I18N support. Spring has a small framework for resolving messages, pattern replacement, etc.

With regards to your seconds question: you should always use the smallest possible interface you need. When you are injecting `BeanFactory`, it is probably an `ApplicationContext`, but there is no need to couple your class with such a huge abstraction. Just pick what you are going to use.